# Is there any AWS events listener in Java SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, listener

I want my local Java application to know that some changes made to the item in AWS DynamoDB table. Is it posible without polling? I understand that I should use DynamoDB Stream to invoke AWS Lamda trigger but what should Lambda function do to send information to my local app? If it's possible.

Comment: I'll try to explain more understandably. Local app is interested in special item in AWS DymanoDB. So there's no need of scan through the whole table if there are some changes. The task is to get information about specific item update in local application without polling.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Lambda is not a good fit here. AWS provides reference architectures that will meet your needs. Usually it goes like this:

DynamoDB Stream -> Kinesis Adapter for DynamoDB Streams -> Kinesis Client Library

Take a closer look at these documents:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/

[image]

You can also design your app as this (the top part) and consume events from SQS long polling, but using Kinesis Client Library seems more straightforward and easier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I can't see how KCL brings information about DenamoDB changes to the local app. If local application scans a stream through KCL in a loop, isn't it a kind of polling?

Comment: @Alexander did you managed to find good solution here?